# Accessing elements of a class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to create a class 'triangle' that is expressed as a vector of type 'vertex', with 'vertex' being a structure consisting of 'x' and 'y', which are of type double. I need to have a member function in 'triangle' that returns the area using herons formula, but I can't figure out how to access the separate x and y components of each element of the triangle. Here is my code so far, the trouble comes in the third piece of code - the triangle.cpp file

vertex.h:

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H

#include <iostream>

struct vertex
{
    double x, y;

    vertex(double ix = 0.0, double iy = 0.0)
    {
        x = ix;
        y = iy;
    }
};

#endif // VERTEX_H
```

triangle.h:

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "vertex.h"

class triangle
{
public:
    triangle(vertex iv0 = vertex(), vertex iv1 = vertex(), vertex iv2 = vertex());
    // pre:
    // post: empty triangle

    triangle(const triangle & source);
    // pre:
    // post: triangle created and initialized to given triangle source

    vertex operator[](size_t i) const;
    // pre: 0 <= i < 3
    // post: return vertex i in this triangle

    double area() const;
    //pre:
    //post: returns area of triangle

private:
    std::vector<vertex> v;
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const triangle & t);
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, triangle & t);
#endif // TRIANGLE_H
```

triangle.cpp source file:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "triangle.h"

triangle::triangle(vertex iv0, vertex iv1, vertex iv2)
{
    v = std::vector<vertex> ();
    v[0] = iv0;
    v[1] = iv1;
    v[2] = iv2;
}

triangle::triangle(const triangle &source)
{
    v = source.v;
}

vertex triangle::operator[] (std::size_t i) const
{
    assert(i < v.size());
    return v[i];
}
 //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
double triangle::area() const
{
    int a, b, c;
    double s;
    //need to use something like a = (v[0].y-v[1].y)/(v[0].x-v[1].x) to calculate area,
    //   this syntax is wrong however^^^
    s = (a+b+c)/2;
    return sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
}

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const triangle & t)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        os << t[i] << " ";
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, triangle & t)
{
    std::size_t n;
    vertex vx;

    is >> n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        is >> vx.x >> vx.y;
    }
    return is;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: no error, just need help defining the side lengths of the triangle

Comment: Plus, you don't want to use integers for a, b, and c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you access the vector (`v[0].x` *etc* is correct), but there IS a problem with how you initialise it:

```
triangle::triangle(vertex iv0, vertex iv1, vertex iv2)
{
    v = std::vector<vertex> ();
    v[0] = iv0;
    v[1] = iv1;
    v[2] = iv2;
}
```

The vector has zero size.  You can't just shove items onto it.  Either use the `push_back` member, or set the size explicitly.  In fact, using a vector at all is questionable.  A triangle does not need an arbitrary number of vertices.  It needs exactly 3.  An array would be fine.

Here are the two vector-based options I mentioned:

```
// Using push_back
triangle::triangle(vertex iv0, vertex iv1, vertex iv2)
{
    v.reserve(3);
    v.push_back(iv0);
    v.push_back(iv1);
    v.push_back(iv2);
}

// Preallocating a vector size before modifying elements
triangle::triangle(vertex iv0, vertex iv1, vertex iv2)
    : v(3)
{
    v[0] = iv0;
    v[1] = iv1;
    v[2] = iv2;
}
```